# Limiting allowed to execute functions in clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to execute clojure functions from a text file and I want to limit subset of available functions due to security reasons. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Raynes/clojail](https://github.com/Raynes/clojail) library which provides features you are requesting and is used to run [Try Clojure](http://www.tryclj.com/) and IRC bot - [lazybot](https://github.com/flatland/lazybot).